formatting options in delphi doesnt seem to work as how I expect it
I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand or confirm if there is a bug in Delphi.
My preference is to have my inline variables start on the same line, but every time I format the source, it starts an inline variable on a new line. This happens regardless of whether I select "Yes", "No", or "As Is".
I have added an image of the IDE; perhaps someone can explain it to me. The documentation states:

Line breaks in Var and Const sections
Defines whether to insert line breaks before each element in Var and
Const sections. The default is Yes.
Online documentation: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Formatter_Options



I guess, inline var declarations are not taken into account with this option at all

@DelphiCoder, I opened a feature request with Embarcadero
